# Default installation location

Tags: windows, windows-7

The default installation location of our applications is `c:\Program Files` folder. Due to virtulization, this is not a good location to install our applications in `'Program Files'` folder in Windows 7. What is the preferred default installation location in Windows 7..

Does microsoft say specify anything on this?
Where can I get more information on this?

Our application can create projects which are kept in c:\Program Files\PolyCd\Projects folder. User can copy these files to other machines to use the project files. We also don't want to run the application as administrator to avoid prompting whenever the application starts. This enables virtualizations. And hence the user won't be able to see the project files he created in c:\Program Files\PolyCd\Projects folder

I have one more question. What is the preferred location of keeping the application specific data such as the project information I mentioned earlier

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea to install it under Program Files? Are you storing configuration there?

Comment: I believe that Program Files or, on a 64-bit OS when installing a 32-bit application, Program Files (x86), are the preferred locations for installing applications. Why exactly can't you install in those locations?

Comment: Do not change this location. That *is* the preferred installation location.

Comment: @DontCare4Free,@Thomas Owens - I have edited my post to make the question more specific and described the problems we are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, thanks for the clarification. Your problem is where you are storing the data. Generally, settings and the likes should be stored in the folder specified by the environment variable `AppData`. Project data, documents, etc however should generally be stored in the user's "Documents" folder.

Comment: @DontCare4Free: Thanks. I am not fully clear about the concept. Where can I get more information on this?. Also the same application should work in the same way in different Operating systems like Windows Xp and Windows 7

Comment: @Maanu I think `%AppData%` should work in both. I'm not sure but I think there's an environment variable for the Documents folder too.

Comment: @DontCare4Free: Is it OK to create a sub folder inside documents folder for our application? Where does applications usually keep their log files Inside Documents folder or somewhere else?

Comment: @Maanu: Yes, generally, you should always make a sub-folder for your application (except for general documents), I think. I would usually place log files inside an application sub-folder in `%AppData%` since they aren't really of that much value for the users to pass around, except for when it's for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Maanu, my rule is if the user wants to get to it (eg you're writing Visual Studio and the user wants to get to the projects they made) put it under Documents (because there's a node on the start menu making Documents easy to find), otherwise under AppData. If several users will share a setting on the same machine, it goes under ProgramData.

Comment: @Kate: I agree completely and wholeheartedly. +1

Answer (score 1):

'Program Files' or 'Program Files (x86)' for 32-bit software on 64-bit Windows. But you would usually use a variable like $PROGRAMFILES so Windows finds the folder itself.

Comment: Exactly. This doesn't answer the OP though as he states that he can't use it because of the virtualization that windows applies. However, it seems more like a design flaw in the application.

Comment: But @Maanu is wrong that virtualization prevents installing it under program files. It only prevents installing it under program files and then writing files to "the current directory". Installing somewhere else is a poor solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked specifically "does Microsoft say anything on this?" let me show you the [Windows logo requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=27028822-B172-4CEC-91A3-26B610A4DA79&displaylang=en) from Microsoft. After you download that document, you can read guidance that includes what folder to install to (Program Files) and where to keep the user's data and settings (ProgramData or AppData). If you follow these guidelines, not only will your application behave as users expect, you will find it easy to get the Windows Logo for your application, which is a shortcut into the partner program. Many of my clients save tends of thousands of dollars on software by being in the partner program, so don't dismiss the value of the logo. But the immediate value to you is clear direction about where to put your app and where to put the user's data.